# Rails3 routing precedence

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm creating a simple CMS with Rails 3. In my `routes.rb` file I have the following entry to catch all routes:

```
match '*url', :controller => 'site', :action => 'dynamic_page'
```

I'm using `ckeditor` gem for editor support. My `rake routes` is as follows:

```
                     root        /(.:format)                              {:action=>"index", :controller=>"site"}
                                 /*url(.:format)                          {:action=>"dynamic_page", :controller=>"site"}
        ckeditor_pictures GET    /ckeditor/pictures(.:format)             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"ckeditor/pictures"}
        ckeditor_pictures POST   /ckeditor/pictures(.:format)             {:action=>"create", :controller=>"ckeditor/pictures"}
         ckeditor_picture DELETE /ckeditor/pictures/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"ckeditor/pictures"}
ckeditor_attachment_files GET    /ckeditor/attachment_files(.:format)     {:action=>"index", :controller=>"ckeditor/attachment_files"}
ckeditor_attachment_files POST   /ckeditor/attachment_files(.:format)     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"ckeditor/attachment_files"}
 ckeditor_attachment_file DELETE /ckeditor/attachment_files/:id(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"ckeditor/attachment_files"}
```

My problem is, as you can see:

```
/*url(.:format)     {:action=>"dynamic_page", :controller=>"site"}
```

..loads before the ckeditor routes and hence ckeditor routes are not working. Can someone help me out on loading ckeditor routes before:

```
/*url(.:format)     {:action=>"dynamic_page", :controller=>"site"}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came up with is adding the ckeditor routes to the `routes.rb` file manually

like this

```
namespace :ckeditor, :only => [:index, :create, :destroy] do
    resources :pictures
    resources :attachment_files
end

match '*url', :controller => 'site', :action => 'dynamic_page'
```

Now its working fine

Answer (score 1):

The routes files is processed in order from top to bottom, so just change the order of the routes so that your catch-all is after the ckeditor stuff.

Comment: Hi @Richard, thanks for the answer, but the question is 'ckeditor' routes are coming from the 'ckeditor' gem's routes. But all my other routing are in config/routes.rb,